# Load Embedded Resources from dynamically loaded assemblies

Tags: c#, wpf, uri, embedded-resource, bitmapimage

I have Class Library project that creates a dll that I side load into my main application dynamically. The main application contains API calls that I use and one of the calls is to load an icon image into a WPF button. I provide `"pack://application:,,,/NamespaceOfMyDll;Component/Resources/embeddedresource.ico"`
as my URI source and following is the code that tries to load this image

```
var logo = new BitmapImage();
 logo.BeginInit();
 logo.UriSource = new Uri(source);
 logo.EndInit();
```

The image is an **embedded resource** of the dll that I am side loading. Doing this throws an exception saying the source is not found.
The project that is trying to load the image has no reference to the dll that I am side loading.
Is there a way to load the image without having to put it in the main application project?

Comment: You mean you have an image inside a dll and you want to use it in your main app ?

Comment: Yes, the image is an embedded resource.

Comment: so, you are not referencing the assembly ?

Comment: No, project where the image is being loaded as no reference to the dll with the image. The main application uses MEF to load these side dlls.

Comment: I will add an answer … maybe it'll help

Comment: Not sure who added the answer and deleted it but using making it a "Resource" instead of "Embedded Resource" did the trick. Thank You!

Comment: what !!!!!?????

Comment: can you checkout my answer and see if it's useful ?

Comment: Yes, apparently Adding URI can not point to Embedded Resources

Comment: But how is it even possible ? You said you want to access a file which is embeded in an assembly's resource and you can't even add reference to it....So, how did you even solve your problem ?

Comment: Yes, I was packing the image in my dll as an "Embedded Resource" which apparently can not be accessed using URI. After changing the Build Action to pack it as "Resource", it is being found correctly now and the icon loads properly in my main application.

Comment: Okay....But as the answer was removed, can you try out my answer and see if it works ? If it does, you must mark it as answer so that other's who face this problem in future may get proper assistance/solution :)

Comment: Will do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround you can go with :

When you add images to the class's resource(I mean in Resources.resx file of the class), create public variables for each resource you add/you want to access. Sample :

```
 public static class TestClass
{
public static Bitmap Image1 { get { return Resource1.Image1; } }
public static Bitmap Image2 { get { return Resource1.Image2; } }
}
```

Now, let's move on to loading the .dll into the main project :

```
Assembly Mydll = Assembly.Load("dll path here");
Type MyLoadClass = MyDALL.GetType("dllAssemblyName.ClassName"); 
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(MyLoadClass);
```

Now, try to access the `Bitmap` variables :

```
Bitmap img1 = (Bitmap)obj.GetType().GetField("Image1").GetValue(obj);

///use the bitmap the way you want :)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using Build Action "Resource" instead of "Embedded Resource" solved the issue.

"Resource is for WPF applications when you want to use uri's to link to resources. Embedded resource is an embedded resource for WinForms applications that should be accessed via a ResourceManager."
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29b6d203-18fb-40b0-a01f-d5b787ccf3be/build-action-resource-vs-embedded-resource?forum=netfxbcl

Comment: This is not a proper answer..... If it solved your issue, then it is pretty ridiculous